# Comparing Java Strings.equals() method yields incorrect Boolean Expression

Tags: java, string, equals

I am using Java String.equals() method to compare two strings.
The Strings are fetched from a File, which is first read and stored each word individually by Splitting Strings using String.split() method.

But, the method equals is not yielding "true" for some String which is exactly same.

Here, I'm implementing Login Program which accepts username and password and checks from the file.dat whether the user exists or not and if exists, whether he is providing correct password or not.

Below is the Logic Snippet:

```
for( int j = 0; j < attrib.length-1; j += 2 )
{
 if( j == 0 )
  attrib[j] = attrib[j].replace("null","");
 if( u.equals( attrib[j] ) )
 {
  if( p.equals( attrib[j+1] ) )
  {
   System.out.println("Sucess");
   chk++;
   break;
  }
 }
 if( chk == 1 )
  break;
}
```

Point me out where I'm wrong.

Here is the File Content from "file.dat":

```
ritwik/1234/ezio/5678
```

And, Here is the terminal output:
[Terminal Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I5Qzx.jpg)

Comment: "the method equals is not yielding "true" for some String which is exactly the same. Yes, it does. Did you debug your code? have checked all the values that are compared? also: "Test" and "Test " are not the same, so this won't lead to a true, for instance

Comment: Could you please include the definition of `u` and `attrib`?

Comment: "equals is not yielding "true" for some String which is exactly same." Then they're not exactly the same. Try looking at the result of `String.toCharArray()` for each of the two strings - they may contain non-printable characters, or maybe codepoints which *look* the same (or similar), but aren't.

Comment: @FelipeSulser The snippet above is existing inside a method int verify(String u, String p), where u and p are Username and Password passed as a parameter from main() method.
The String[] atrrib is used to contain the Strings split from data (String containing the values read from the file "file.dat"), which is defined as : attrib = data.split("/", -1);

Comment: Add more details or post a reproducible example. Not sure if you read everything into attrib.

Comment: Why are you checking for if( j == 0 ) and replacing only at index 0 ?

Comment: @tak3shi Because at j == 0, if I didn't replace, I was getting "null" appended at the first element of attrib.

Comment: what is the type and content of attrib?

Comment: @tak3shi 'attrib' contains the content of "file.dat".
Thus, 'attrib[0] = nullritwik' (without replacing null)
          'attrib[1] = 1234'
          'attrib[2] = ezio'
          'attrin[3] = 5678'

Comment: With the information you have provided, the code works. So the problem must be somewhere else. Check dquijada answer and use a debuger to find your problem. This can be done within seconds.

Answer (score 1):

If *u* is a String and *attrib* a String array, it will return the correct boolean.

Check if both Strings are the same. Usual mistakes:

**1.** String.equals is case-sensitive. So "Hello" and "hello" are not equal.

**2.** String.equals doesn't trim (remove spaces). So "Hello" and "Hello " are not equal.

If both of this fail, just use

```
System.out.println ("." + u + "==" + attrib[i] + ".");
```

before comparing, so you can see if they are both exactly the same, maybe there is something wrong when you initialize. (The points are to make it easier to detect spaces, but of course they are not needed).

EDIT: If this ALSO fails, try printing the char array of the string (`u.toCharArray()`), in case it has some weird chars in the middle.

Comment: even if you trim, "Hello" and "Hell o" will return false, since trimming only removes leading and tailing spaces, not spaces in the middle of the String

Comment: @dquijada thanks for the tip.

I figured out that the array attrib was containing white spaces using attrib[j].length().
Then, I trimmed the contents, and viola, My Code starts working as expected.